# github build failed, no matching provisioning profile found

Tags: ios, xcode, github

i am a completely beginner swift coder, 
i learn from online tutorials and some code i manage to download,

all the projects i download from apple dev website work perfectly,
but none of the projects i have downloaded on Github work,
i can't build any of them,

i guess it's something related to the build settings,
"no code signing identities found" seems to be the main issue,

can you tell me how to solve that please?

i code on mac book, with the latest updates for mac OS and Xcode.

cheers,

Comment: Are you trying to put the application on an iOS device or are you running it in the simulator? More information about how you're running this application woud be helpful. It sounds like you're trying to run your app on a device. If you want to do this, you need an Apple Developer account, then you'll have the Signing Identity you need. Visit: http://developer.apple.com

Comment: I don't have yet an Apple developer account, because I first want to improve my coding skills. But if some sample projects can only be tested on device, not on the simulator, so it's not very convenient. I have checked again, all the projects I can't build, I always choose ios simulator. And about the console log, seems it's empty. So far I have managed to build zero projects from github. But thanks for your answers.